# click() event is calling twice in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I setup a link element and called its click event in jQuery but the click event is calling twice, please see below the code of jQuery.

```
$("#link_button")
.button()
.click(function () {
   $("#attachmentForm").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: The problem is probably from somewhere else in your script.

Comment: if you cannot find where you made things to call this twice, make a unbind('clik') before the click(...).

Comment: regilero: exactly, the whole code base is very large. where should I put that unbind?

Comment: you can detect what functions are binding to that click event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool

Answer (score 259, accepted):

Make sure and check that you have not accidentally included your script twice in your HTML page.

Comment: This was the problem for my case. That my click event was getting bubbeled. Thanks for the pointer. :) +1

Comment: I just looked at this solution and laughed thinking "I'm not stupid enough to do that"... turns out I had done exactly this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks! This turned out to be the problem for me too. Had it in a laravel blade template and in a nested template that called @parent on the same section name. Oops. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Struggled with this for over 20 hours, and this tip led me to the right path. I was using the MVC ScriptBundles but was also linking to the script files directly and this duplicated the events

Comment: lol... I've been there... I was putting the blame on the third party, but it was me who linked the .js file twice.

Comment: This is hilarious but another idiot here. How to debug this kind of double include?

Comment: Hah... this was driving me up the wall. Been banging my head on my desk for an hour until I found this answer. Now I just feel dumb :P

Comment: That was a subtle one. It also explains why the debugger was doing dumb things. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using a callback to register the click handler, make sure that callback isn't being called multiple times.  If it gets called more than once, you will have N-1 too many click events fired.

Comment: @RajaKhoury can you please mention it was which extension, as I am similar issue, going crazy, code works fine at all the clients end except one who is using chrome. Thanks

Comment: @abbas I can't remember at all :( I am sorry. Did you try to disable all your extensions ?

Answer (score 81):

Make un unbind before the click;

```
$("#link_button").unbind('click');
$("#link_button")
.button()
.click(function () {
   $("#attachmentForm").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: try $("#link_button").unbind(); or make a simple test to check how many times that code is read, if more than once...

Comment: that's just fixing the error on the fly each time, not a real solution. it does the trick and has helped me but you should find the real problem and make a permanent fix.

Comment: it's really useful in my case, because I need to call several times the methods with my events after some ajax calls it starts to become overclicked(I don't know if this word exist). For my situation it means a solution.

Comment: Fixed my problem with a script that was only included once. Thank you!

Comment: @ThiagoC.SVentura True, I have the same situation as you said. This saved me!

Answer (score 56):

It means your code included the jquery script twice.
But try this:

```
$("#btn").unbind("click").click(function(){

//your code

});
```

Answer (score 42):

I tried , 
`e.stopImmediatePropagation()`; 
This seems to work for me.

Comment: @BasheerAL-MOMANI See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299740/stoppropagation-vs-stopimmediatepropagation

Comment: Thank you, it's work... by the way after reading understand it prevent any parent handlers from being executed

Comment: This work for me and the following link will help to understand the function https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stopimmediatepropagation.asp

Answer (score 21):

In my case I used the below script to overcome the issue

```
$('#id').off().on('click',function(){
    //...
});
```

`off()` unbinds all the events bind to `#id`.
If you want to unbind only the `click` event, then use `off('click')`.

Answer (score 9):

A rather common solution to the two click problem is putting

```
e.stopPropagation()
```

at the end of your function (assuming you use `function(e)` that is).  This prevents the event from bubbling up which could lead to a second execution of the function.

Comment: Best answer of the bunch.

Answer (score 9):

Simply call .off() right before you call .on().

This will remove all event handlers:

```
$(element).off().on('click', function() {
// function body
});
```

To only remove registered 'click' event handlers:

```
$(element).off('click').on('click', function() {
// function body
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, but you can try changing this code

```
$("#link_button")
.button()
.click(function () {
   $("#attachmentForm").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

to this:

```
$("#link_button").button();
$("#link_button").unbind("click").click(function () {
   $("#attachmentForm").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

For me, this code solved the problem.
But take care not to accidentally include your script twice in your HTML page.
I think that if you are doing these two things correctly, your code will work correctly. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Adding `e.preventDefault();` at the start of my function worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely a bug specially while it's FireFox. I searched alot tried all the above answers and finally got it as bug by many experts over SO. So, I finally came up with this idea by declaring variable like

```
var called = false;
$("#ColorPalete li").click(function() {
    if(!called)
    {
             called = true;
             setTimeout(function(){ //<-----This can be an ajax request but keep in mind to set called=false when you get response or when the function has successfully executed.
                 alert('I am called');
                 called = false;
             },3000);

    }
});
```

In this way it first checks rather the function was previously called or not.

Answer (score 3):

this snippet of code contains nothing bad. It's another part of your script as @karim told

Answer (score 3):

please try this

```
$('#ddlSupervisor').live('change', function (e) {
    if (e.handled !== true) { //this makes event to fire only once
    getEmployeesbySupervisor();
    e.handled = true;
   }
});
```

Comment: I changed "live" to "on" and it seems to work for me. So event fires for only time time when the button is clicked.

Comment: This is spot on.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why but I had this problem with

```
$(document).on("click", ".my-element", function (e) { });
```

When I changed it to

```
$(".my-element").click(function () { });
```

Problem was solved. But definitely something wrong in my code.

Comment: this worked for me in laravel, dont know what cause this issue

Comment: I have same problem. The problem is your solution may not work if you are generating html markup after document was loaded

Answer (score 3):

This is an older question, but if you are using event delegation this is what caused it for me.

After removing `.delegate-two` it stopped executing twice. I believe this happens if both delegates are present on the same page.

```
$('.delegate-one, .delegate-two').on('click', '.button', function() {
    /* CODE */
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was working fine in Chrome and IE was calling the `.click()` twice. if that was your issue, then I fixed it by return false, after calling the `.click()` event

```
   $("#txtChat").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            $('#btnChat').click();
            $('#txtChat').val('');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `unbind` solved my problem:

```
$("#btn").unbind("click").click(function() {
    // your code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure thing somewhere else in your script(s) the "click" event is being bound again to the same element, as several other answers / comments are suggesting.

I had a similar problem and in order to verify that, I simply added a `console.log` command to my script, like in the following snippet:

```
$("#link_button")
    .button()
    .click(function () {
        console.log("DEBUG: sliding toggle...");
        $("#attachmentForm").slideToggle("fast");
    });
```

If, upon clicking the button, you get something similar to the image below from your browser's developer console (as I did), then you know for sure that the `click()` event has been bound twice to the same button.

[image: the developer's console]

If you need a quick patch, the solution proposed by other commentators of using the `off` method (btw `unbind` is deprecated since jQuery 3.0) to unbind the event before (re)binding it works well, and I recommend it too:

```
$("#link_button")
    .button()
    .off("click")
    .click(function () {
        $("#attachmentForm").slideToggle("fast");
    });
```

Unfortunately, this is only a temporary patch! Once the problem of making you boss happy is resolved, you should really dig into your code a little more and fix the "duplicated binding" problem.

The actual solution depends of course on your specific use case. In my case, for example, there was a problem of "context". My function was being invoked as the result of an Ajax call applied to a specific part of the document: reloading the whole document was actually reloading both the "page" and the "element" contexts, resulting in the event being bound to the element twice.

My solution to this problem was to leverage the jQuery [one](https://api.jquery.com/on/) function, which is the same as [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) with the exception that the event is automatically unbound after its first invocation. That was ideal for my use case but again, it might not be the solution for other use cases.

Answer (score 1):

When I use this method on load page with jquery, I write `$('#obj').off('click');` before set the click function, so the bubble not occurs. Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got tricked by a selection matching multiple items so each was clicked. `:first` helped:

```
$('.someClass[data-foo="'+notAlwaysUniqueID+'"]:first').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

I too had this issue on FF. My tag was however bound to an `<a>` tag. Though the `<a>` tag wasn't going anywhere it still did the double click. I swapped the `<a>` tag for a `<span>` tag instead and the double click issue disappeared.

Another alternative is to remove the href attribute completely if the link isn't going anywhere.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd: Actually, it is an answer. Even if formulated to raise red flags.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue because my `$(elem).click(function(){});` script was placed inline in a div that was set to `style="display:none;"`.

When the css display was switched to block, the script would add the event listener a second time. I moved the script to a separate .js file and the duplicate event listener was no longer initiated.

Answer (score 1):

My simple answer was to turn the click bind into a function and call that from the onclick of the element - worked a treat! whereas none of the above did

Answer (score 0):

*If your event is calling twice or three times, or more, this might help.*

If you are using something like this to trigger events…

```
$('.js-someclass').click();
```

…then pay attention to the number of `.js-someclass` elements you have on the page, because it'll trigger the click event for all elements – and not just once!

A simple fix then is to make sure you trigger the click just once, [by selecting just the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11345480/1717535), e.g.:

```
$('.js-someclass:first').click();
```

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. This worked for me -

```
$('selector').once().click(function() {});
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Throws an error for me... Plus it's a dirty solution - the function is being run more than once, the solution is to place it somewhere else and use console.log() to monitor things.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the HTML was laid out like this:

```
<div class="share">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="share">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my jQuery was like this:

```
jQuery('.share').toggle();
```

It confused me because nothing appeared to be happening. The problem was that the inner `.share`s `toggle`  would cancel out the outer `.share`s `toggle`.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by change the element type.
instead of button I place input, and this problem don't occur more.

instesd of:

```
<button onclick="doSomthing()">click me</button>
```

replace with:

```
<input onclick="doSomthing()" value="click me">
```