# Copying html to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, html-lists

What I am doing is whenever I click a `li.opn` I get the respective `.pst` 's html from `#hiddenDiv` .

If the `.pst` 's html is empty then do a `$.post()` to get the `html` from server.

But my problem is if I receive a `<script></script>` **code from server** in `outputHTML` then the `document` **gets 2 scripts**

- One in `displayDiv`
- Another in `hiddenDiv`

This causes various bugs like the `script` function runs twice.

**UPDATE**

Here's my [**My Problem Solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731894/click-event-is-calling-twice-in-jquery) but i have to use the `same html,js` codes twice!! Any help ???

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li class="opn" set="stack">Stackoverflow</li>
   <li class="opn" set="google">Google</li>
</ul>


<div id="hiddenDiv">
 <div class="pst" set="stack"></div>
 <div class="pst" set="google"></div>
</div>
<div id="displayDiv"></div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$('.opn').click(function(){
var set = $(this).attr('set');
if($('.pst[set="'+set+'"]').html() > 0){
  $('#displayDiv').html($('.pst[set="'+set+'"]').html());
}else{
   $.post(url,{},function(data){
        var outputHTML = data.output; 
        $('#displayDiv').html(outputHTML);
        $('.pst[set="'+set+'"]').html(outputHTML);
      },'json');
 }
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE2**

If this is the output from server then *'asik was clicked'* is showing **2 times**

```
<div>
     <button class="asik">Click Me</button>
</div>
<script>$('.asik').click(function(){alert('asik was clicked');})</script>
```

Comment: What is your server html?

Comment: lol php @AhosanKarimAsik

Comment: what is your output code form server?

Comment: .e.g `<div><button class="asik">Click Me</button></div><script>$('.asik').click(function(){alert('asik was clicked');})</script>` @AhosanKarimAsik

Comment: If remove script from server data, then have any problem? if have no problem then remove script by regex or dom parser..

Comment: "yes i have a problem!" @AhosanKarimAsik the `script` part is part of the program functioning how can i remove it!!

Comment: You add output data two times. so, this problem. and solution is : collect data by two data(html & script) variable . and get these. set html in two position but script set into one position .  or anather solution will give you by answer

Comment: ok then answer @AhosanKarimAsik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**  Remove script from server data and put that script following comment..

```
    if($('.pst[set="'+set+'"]').html() > 0){
      $('#displayDiv').html($('.pst[set="'+set+'"]').html());
    // server script put here..
    }else{
       $.post(url,{},function(data){
            var outputHTML = data.output; 
            $('#displayDiv').html(outputHTML);
            $('.pst[set="'+set+'"]').html(outputHTML);
    //// server script put here..
$('.asik').click(function(){alert('asik was clicked');});
          },'json');
     }
```