# Strange behaviour using .on() for click event - Fired twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I already checked answers about click events fired twice. But I have a question about using `.on()`.

Usually, I use it like this on dynamically added elements, and it always worked fine:

```
$(document).on("click", "dynElement", function(){})
```

In the current website I'm working on, I use it several times. But in the function that I'm trying to achieve, let's say, a dynamic "jump to page", click on page number is triggered twice:

```
$(document).on("click", ".jumpTo .number", function(){
    console.log("Jump");
});
```

Trying to find the origin of this behaviour, I tried this syntax that works fine:

```
$(".jumpTo").on("click", ".number", function(){
    console.log("Jump");
});
```

Can anyone explain what is the difference between these two different syntaxes (which look quite similar to me)?

And **optionally**, why is `$(document).on("click", ".jumpTo .number", function(){})` triggered twice? (Optionally because I am not able to reproduce this behaviour in a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0xnwrnL/), everything works as it is supposed to).

Comment: Do any of these answers help you? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6731894/3132718 Most probably the one with `.unbind()`?

Comment: You are triggering a click on both selectors at the same time...

Comment: @Al.G. , it helps, I check everything in these answers. But usually, I do not need to unbind() click events

Comment: So it helps or it solved your problem?

Comment: @Shikkediel That's completely false. `.jumpTo .number` means a child element of "jumpTo" with class "number". You're thinking about `.jumpTo, .number` (with a comma).

Comment: If you are unable to reproduce this in a Fiddle then it must be something else that is causing this. Either provide more code or try to create a working Fiddle by slowly stripping parts from the existing code.

Comment: @Al.G. : that's not solving my problem. Still fired twice

Comment: @Shikkediel No, the HTML is like `<div class="jumpTo"><span class="number"></span></div>` so `.jumpTo .number` is correct. @EdenSource Maybe you call `.on()` twice on the same elements which will add two event handlers ...?

Comment: @SaphuA : I 'll try to provide a better Fiddle.

Comment: @devnull69 : I promise I check this ;)

Comment: In your fiddle you are adding all sub elements at the same time. If (in your original code) you are adding them one by one and each time you call `on()` it will bind additional handlers each time

Comment: @devnull69: good Point, but there is only one call for `on()`, only content is updated without binding additional click handler

Comment: Do you, by any chance, create nested `.number` elements inside `.jumpTo`? In that case you should use `'.jumpTo > .number'` as a selector for .on()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", ".jumpTo .number", function(){
    console.log("Jump");
});
```

In this case the click handler is set on the document object. So whenever you click somewhere on the page, it will fire and look for a ".jumpTo .number" element inside it. If it finds it, it will check if the click was on it and your function will execute.

```
$(".jumpTo").on("click", ".number", function(){
    console.log("Jump");
});
```

Here the click handler will be on .jumpTo

As Al.G said probably this code gets executed multiple times, so you actually add that handler multiple times, hence the double firing.
One way to solve it is to do something like this:

```
$(".jumpTo").unbind("click").on("click"...
```

Another is to change your code to make sure the .on() call doesn't get executed twice.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's showing the two versions only as example. It fires twice on the first one, but works correctly when using the second.

Comment: @Lacho Tomov: Thanks for the explaination, I now know the difference between these 2 ways to handle `on()`.

Comment: If it fires twice only in the first case, this might be because there are multiple ".jumpTo .number" elements? Also make sure your html correctly validates, it acts strange if you have DOM errors, unclosed tags, etc.

Comment: I just checked all html markup, nothing wrong on this side

Comment: As second case works for me, and Lacho Tomovgave gave me difference between these 2 click handlers, I'll mark my question as "solved". Just don't know why it is trigger twice for first case. Thank you all for helping.

Comment: @EdenSource you sure there isn't multiple instances of ".jumpTo .number" ? I really cannot think of any other reason why it would fire 2 times... What happens when you run that in the js console: $(".jumpTo .number").length ? Does it return 1 or more?

Comment: Of course there is more than 1. As in the fiddle, there are 4 instances of ".jumpTo .number". But in the fiddle, console.log return only one "Jump" each click. In my own project, there are 2 "Jump" each click.

Comment: Right, sorry I didn't see the fiddle...
One last thing I can think of:
console.log('check');
$(document).on("click", ".jumpTo .number", function(){
    console.log("Jump");
}); 
This 'check' is printed only once in console, right? I know it's a dumb check, but really cannot think of anything else...