# JQuery also loaded by hosting site, events run multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

After trying several lightbox variations and in the interest of getting back in practice and learning JQuery, decided to try coding my own http://walczak.000webhostapp.com/index.html. The hosting site for a project I'm working on looks to also be loading some form of JQuery. The behavior I'm seeing happens on the 3D pages where I need to present a gallery of images. The first time a gallery is opened, both clicking on a thumbnail image and using the Next / Previous buttons works as expected. However when a second gallery instance is opened, when using the Next / Previous buttons, every other image seems to be shown. 3rd time, every 3rd image. Debugging shows that JQuery is running multiple times. I have tried suggestions from [click() event is calling twice in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731894/click-event-is-calling-twice-in-jquery) with no success.

Also help with why a thumbnail needs to be clicked before the Next / Previous buttons will work (did not have this problem at first) and what I may have missed to solve the dreaded TypeError cannot read property inside the document.ready function on the thumbnail array would be appreciated. relevant code is:

```
On main page
<div class="boxback">
    <div class="box">
    <table>
       <tr>
         <td><a id="prev" href="#"><img class="galleryNav" src="./backgrounds/buttons/lightbox/back.png"></a></td>
         <td><img id="imgbox" src="" alt=""></td>
         <td><a id="next" href="#"><img class="galleryNav" src="./backgrounds/buttons/lightbox/forward.png"></a></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><p id="caption"></p></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

       <div id="thumbs"></div>
       <a id="myClose" href="#"><img src="./backgrounds/buttons/lightbox/close.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

...

```
Loaded content
<ul class="thumbsdiv">
    <li class="clkthumb"><img class="thumbnail" src="./davinci/large/gears/gearsmain.png" alt="Original DaVinci drawing" data-index=0></a></li> 
    <li class="clkthumb"><img class="thumbnail" src="./davinci/large/gears/gears01.png" alt="" data-index=1></a></li>
    <li class="clkthumb"><img class="thumbnail" src="./davinci/large/gears/gears02.png" alt="" data-index=2></a></li>
    <li class="clkthumb"><img class="thumbnail" src="./davinci/large/gears/gears03.png" alt="" data-index=3></a></li>
    (abbreviated ...)
</ul>   

JQuery
var mypath = "";
var myindex = Number(0);
//var imgs = [];

$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".overlay").click(function()
    {
    mypath = $(this).attr("data-gallery");
    mypath += " .thumbsdiv";        

    $("#thumbs").load(mypath);
    $(".boxback").css("display","block");
    $(".box").css("display","inline-block");
    $("#imgbox").attr("src",$(this).attr("data-image"));
    $("#imgbox").attr("alt",$(this).attr("data-alt"));
    $("#caption").text($(this).attr("data-alt"));
    myindex = Number($(this).attr("data-index"));

    do{
        if (document.readyState === "complete") 
            {                                       $(document).on("click",".thumbnail",thumbClick);
            $(document).on("click","#prev,#next",nextImg);
            $(".thumbnail")[myindex].trigger("click");
            //$('[data-index = "0"]').click();
            }
        } while(document.readyState !== "complete");
    })
});

function thumbClick()
{   
//   $("#imgbox").attr("src","");
//   $("#imgbox").attr("alt","");
   $("#caption").text("");
   $("#imgbox").attr("src",$(this).attr("src"));
   $("#imgbox").attr("alt",$(this).attr("alt"));
    myindex = Number($(this).attr("data-index"));
   $("#caption").text($(this).attr("alt"));
$(".thumbnail").css({"border-style":"none"});
$(this).css({"border-style":"solid",
            "border-color":"#000",
            "border-size":"1px"});
 event.stopImmediatePropagation();
};

//$("#prev,#next").click(function nextImg()
function nextImg()
{
    var imgs = $(".thumbnail");

   if ($(this).attr("id") == "next")
    {myindex++;}
   else {myindex--;}

   if (myindex <= -1)
    {myindex = imgs.length - 1;}

   if (myindex >= imgs.length)
    {myindex = 0;}

    imgs[myindex].click();
};
```

Comment: each time you click on overlay, you are adding an onclick listener to "#prev,#next" and ".thumbnail"

Comment: I tried using $(document).unbind.on("click",".thumbnail",thumbClick); with no effect. And different thumbnails are loaded depending on which image on the "main" page is clicked

Comment: move $(document).on("click",".thumbnail",thumbClick); and            $(document).on("click","#prev,#next",nextImg); to the beginning of your code