# how can I create an html article for each element in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i want to iterate a response and create an article section with each object

I have the following piece of code that makes the request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://0.0.0.0:5001/api/v1/places_search/",
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (list_of_places) {
            for (let place of list_of_places) {
                $(".places").append("<article></article>");

                // title box
                $(".places article").append(`<div class="title_box">
                 <h2>${place['name']}</h2>
                 <div class="price_by_night">${place['price_by_night']}</div>
                 </div>`);
            }

        }

    });
```

here's a snippet of the html to edit:

```
<section class="places">
            <!-- <h1>Places</h1> -->
</section>
```

here's a screenshot of the result of the snippet:

[image: image of result of code snippet above]

How can I get only one object per article instead of all objects left in the iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because within your `for` loop, `$(".places article")` is selecting *all* elements matching that selector in the DOM, so you repeatedly append the new items to each one.

To fix this you can `append()` the content to the `article` you just created:

```js
for (let place of list_of_places) {
  const $article = $('<article />').appendTo('.places');
  $article.append(`<div class="title_box"><h2>${place.name}</h2><div class="price_by_night">${place.price_by_night}</div></div>`);
}
```

Alternatively you can use `map()` instead of your `for` loop to create an array of HTML strings which you append to the DOM as a whole:

```js
const html = list_of_places.map(place => `<article><div class="title_box"><h2>${place.name}</h2><div class="price_by_night">${place.price_by_night}</div></div></article>`);
$('.places').append(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".places article").eq(-1).append(`<div class="title_box">...
```

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31546638/5217142) to [How do I select a single element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/307500/5217142) in conjunction looking up  [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) in jQuery docs.